# Finding all integers a such that $a^3+a+1\equiv0 \pmod 5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just by eyeballing it and testing several values, I sense that the form  $a^3+a+1$ is one such that it is never $\equiv0 \pmod 5$ as I can find no unique solution to start with and it seems to follow the pattern of $1,3,1,1,4,1,3,1,1,4,\ldots$

However, I don't know how to prove this intuition (assuming I am correct and no integer $a$ satisfies this form).

I am aware that this may be rewritten as finding all $a$ such that $a^3+a\equiv4 \pmod 5$, but that doesn't seem to illuminate the point.

Comment: By 'several values' do you mean $a\equiv 0,1,2,3,4\pmod 5$?

Comment: After noting that $(a + 5k)^3 \equiv a^3 \pmod 5$ for all integers $k$, one can assume that $0 \le a < 5$.

Comment: Never forget this: if $a\equiv a'$ and $b\equiv b'$ with respect to the same modulus, then $a+b\equiv a'+b'$, $a-b\equiv a'-b'$, and $ab\equiv a'b'$. This is all you need to know for this kind of matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,a\,$ is an integer such that $\,f(a) = a^3+a+1\equiv 0\pmod5\,$ then also $f(b)\equiv 0\pmod 5\,$ for all $\,b\equiv a\pmod 5.\,$ In particular this is true for $\,b = (a\ {\rm mod}\ 5) = \,$ the remainder of $\,a\,$  mod $5$. Thus, since the set $\,\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ is a complete set of remainders mod $5$, if none of them are roots, we conclude that no integers are roots. But you have already shown that, so you are done.

**Remark** $\ $ Above I used that $\,a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\,f(a)\equiv f(b).\,$ This is true for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with *integer* coefficients, because such polynomials evaluated at an integer are compositions of integer sums and products, and both of these operations *preserve* congruences - see the rules below. For example,  $\,\rm A\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, A^3 \equiv a^3\,$ by the Power Rule, so $\rm\,A^3+A\equiv a^3+a\,$ by the Sum Rule.

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\quad  A\equiv a,\quad B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{A+B\,\equiv\, a+b}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a) + (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#0a0}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a,\ \ and \ \  B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#c00}{AB - ab} $

**Congruence Power Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ A^n\equiv a^n\ \  (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\ $ It is true for $\rm\,n=1\,$ and $\rm\,A\equiv a,\ A^n\equiv a^n \Rightarrow\, A^{n+1}\equiv a^{n+1},\,$ by the Product Rule, so the result follows by induction on $\,n.$

**Beware** $ $ that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of above $\rm A^B\equiv a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b,\,$ so it reduces to the Power Rule, so follows by inductively applying $\,\rm b\,$ times the Product Rule).

Answer (score 2):

From Fermat's theorem $a^4\equiv 1 \mod 5$ for $a \not \equiv 0\mod 5$. If $a\equiv0 \mod 5$ the result is obvious. So assume $a \not \equiv 0 \mod 5$

Hence
$$
a^3+a+1 = \frac{1}{a} {a^4+a^2+a} = \frac{1+a+a^2}{a} = \frac{(a-1)^3}{(a-1) a} ~~~\text{if $a \not \equiv 1 \mod 5$}$$
Result follows since $(a-1)^3 \equiv 0$ only when $a\equiv1$

You can generalize this to:
If $3$ does not divide $p-1$ then $p$ does not divide
$$
a^{p-2} + a + 1$$
using the same logic.

The reason I give the generalization is you can expect something like this in an exam!